# Why does this always evaluates to true no matter what argument you apply to it?

Tags: javascript

I am reading 'JavaScript Allongé' and came across this in a section about functions.

```
function (value) {
  return (function (copy) {
    return copy === value
  })(value)
}(value);
```

Say I pass 5... a string, a function, an array or ANYTHING as an argument for that matter! Why would it evaluate to true? Nothing seems to be passed to the argument ***copy*** which is nothing? The only thing I can think of is, when you pass 5 to value, its also being dropped in the argument in the return function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(function (value) {         // function accepts a `value` as an argument
  return (function (copy) { // function accepts a `copy` argument
    return copy === value   // `copy` and `value` are both 5
  })(value)                 // `value` becomes `copy` on line 2
}(5));                      // pass in 5, becomes `value` on line 1
```

In other words:

1. 5 gets passed to first outer function, which accepts a `value` argument (`value` is now `5`)
2. inner function is called with `value`, which accepts a `copy` argument (`copy` is now equal to `value`, which is equal to `5`)
3. inner function compares `copy` to `value`, both of which have been set to `5`.

All this is, is a fancy way to set two local variables to the same value, and then compare them.  So as long as a value is equal to itself, this will return true.

Comment: Wait I think I see it...
The value(5) is ALSO being passed in the inner/return function, which is then getting used in the 'copy' variable. Much in the way the outer function is passing 5 to value? :)

Comment: @antonio Correct. There are two self executing functions, and each is passed an argument.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the same object back into the comparison. Therefore it evaluates to `true`. However, there is some stuff happening here that makes this more interesting than following a reference

```
{...})(value)
```

The `(value)` makes it a self [executing function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/), so it is evaluated inline. It's a nice feature of Javascript that it pays to understand. You can use them this way but they are really nice for creating [Javascript Modules](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) that scope and extend code.

Comment: Is it pretty much what we would call aliasing?

Comment: + by mentioning and reference a nice explanation of "self-executing anonymous function"

Answer (score 2):

There is something being passed in to the argument **copy**  The 4th line of your sample is sending **value** in to be used as the argument for **copy**

So if copy is a copy of value, then **copy === value** will always return true.

The syntax in your sample is defining and then immediately calling a function.  This version is logically the same, maybe the behavior makes more sense when seen this way:

```
var funcA = function(value) {
  var funcB = function(copy) {
    return copy === value;
  }
  return funcB(value);
}

result = funcA(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing 5 (value) in the first call.

```js
function (value) {
 /*remove all stuff so you can focus in the firs step.*/
}(5);
```

Then you're returning a "call to a function" that receives "value" (which current value is 5) as parameter received in "copy" (so copy's value now is 5).

```js
//function (value) { commented lines doesn't care yet so you can focus
  return (function (copy) {
    //return copy === value
  })(value)
//}(value);
```

- This inner function returns the comparison of "value" (which is accessible because the inner function have access to outer scope (first function and it's parameters)) and "copy" (wich previously received "value=5")

  - value=5=copy then returns true.

```js
//function (value) { lines doesn't care yet so you can focus
  //return (function (copy) {
     return copy === value
  //})(value)
//}(value);
```

Say it plain you're comparing the same value.